# Pass javascript variable to jstl tags

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl

I need to change (parse) one of the object property. Is it any way I can save the parse value in the js variable and then pass it back. This is what I tried but it does not work:

```
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${requestScope.users}">
       var parsedName= parseUserName("${user.name}");
       <c:set target = "${user}" property = "parsedName" value ="${parsedName}"/>  
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: This looks like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Could you include information about a broader picture of the problem?

Comment: I need to show some user information in my html, but one of the field(name) has to be parsed first

Comment: Add Hole case Scenario rather then just small glimpse of it. Include what you want to parse and how you want to parse and obviously that includes why...

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${requestScope.users}">
    <script type="javascript">
        var parsedName= parseUserName("${user.name}");
    </script>
    <c:set target = "${user}" property = "parsedName" value ="${parsedName}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

unfortunately it is not possible.

The `jstl` code happen on the server side and javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to do what you are trying to do. The only possible solution is to send the variable to the server using a partial refresh and set the required property once the page has been refreshed

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to implement the parseUserName() logic in JSP itself using JSTL.

If you need help with that post the JS method logic here.